# Webview in Android programming

Tags: android-webview, html

I have developed a simple android application in which I have used webview to access a webpage.
When I run the application, I get the error saying webpage does not exist or check your internet connection.
I checked the internet connection and also the same link opens in my computer.
Where am I going wrong?
Do I have to provide some special permissions to the application to access the webpage over internet?
What else could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding missing permission in manifest.

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```